# Can't patch nurbs

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, nurbs-surface

Someone know why when i press F to patch between 2 nurbs curves it just connect the 2 spines instead of patch them?
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "patch" ? What would you like to happen when you press "F" ?

Comment: Sorry, let's do faster if i show you:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1xDvnVovd4     at the minute 6:15 he create a patch between two nurbs still working with nurbs curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a regular nurbs curve, not a "surface" nurbs curve. They are two different objects and you can't work in surface with a regular nurbs curve. They are in two different submenus.

Explanation :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I can not comment yet, but I have an idea

Try "Convert to mesh". If that is what you are looking for, keep in mind that whenever you make changes to the curve itself it is going to affect the already converted mesh.

Comment: No. i'm trying to create geometry still working with nurbs. I won't convert to mesh

Answer (score -1):

so im hoping you got this sorted but just in case, i was playing around with nurbs and found that if you add a nurbs curve from the surface menu position it scale it and position it where you want then go into edit mode and select at least two control points then press E as you would do to extrude it will allow you to drag out a surface, I am after finding this starting to learn blenders nurbs tools and i have to say, its not actually too bad, if you're creating any kind of vehicle then the mirror modifier works as it does with normal meshes, haven't tried any other modifiers, I also haven't found a way to close the nurbs surface but I'm sure you can, i know you can add loop cuts but only by highlighting an entire row and sub dividing that row, hope this was of some help.[image]